# Why image disappears when I add "absolute" in class property?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

### Problem

I am making a basic image carousel with Tailwind; I have been stuck with this problem where I as soon as I add `absolute` on`<li>` tag, the image disappears.

Added "relative" on outer tag as I saw some solutions mentioning it, but it didn't stop the image disappearing.

How can I make the image stop disappearing on browser when I still use the absolute property ?

### Code

Here is my html code.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div
    class="relative m-12">
    <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div class="relative">
            <ul class="m-0 p-0 flex flex-row list-none">
                <li class="absolute top-0 inset-0">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="object-cover object-center h-full block rounded-md"
                                src="https://i.imgur.com/tSxyAT4.jpeg" alt="altText" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `absolute` position to div instead.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="relative m-12">
    <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div class="absolute">
            <ul class="m-0 p-0 flex flex-row list-none">
                <li class="top-0 inset-0">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="object-cover object-center h-full block rounded-md"
                                src="https://i.imgur.com/tSxyAT4.jpeg" alt="altText" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of this line - `<div class="flex justify-center">`

`div` element within is "squished" and have no size (0px because inner elements absolutely positioned and have "no space", while flex layout is not allowing to stretch full width)

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout - [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

To fix it you may add `w-full` to inner `div` like

```html
<div class="relative m-12">
    <div class="flex justify-center">
    
        <!-- here -->
        <div class="relative w-full">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I personally see no reason in such layout (center the only element which is stretched to full width anyway) so desired result may correct my answer